# Is it possible to open a file descriptor by reading /proc/<pid>/fd?

Tags: unix, pipe

I am writing a shell application. The shell will fork of processes and start application through execve.

I would like to reroute stdin in the new process to an unnamed pipe. This pipe would be shared between the application and the parent.

To my understanding the same user and the root can check the opened file descriptors of the spawned processes. This can be done by accessing /proc//fd/ .

Is it possible as root or an application running as the same user, to open the given file descriptor and eavesdrop on it?

TLDR: I am interested how safe are unnamed pipes, and if it is possible to eavesdrop on them.

Comment: `root` or the owner of the process can also use a system call trace (`strace`) to see what data gets read or written to any file descriptor. (On Linux, depending on the system's configuration, a normal user might be restricted to tracing child processes only.)

Comment: were you able to find an answer?